# A story about a beneficial 'disease': 'nerve skin'?

Tags: story-identification

Reading this question [Short story about a sentient disease from a Jovian moon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232016/short-story-about-a-sentient-disease-from-a-jovian-moon), I came to think about a story, probably a novel, I read maybe 40 years ago, in Danish. It was about a kind of infection – the victims were covered in a kind of greyish skin which was strongly innervated, this was labeled 'nerve-skin' (direct translation of the Danish word). The main character gets infected and realises that his senses are getting more powerful and his intelligence increases (I think) as a consequence. Any guess as to which story this is?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41103/novelette-where-human-race-divided-into-those-with-skin-symbiote-and-those-witho

Comment: And https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53407/4495

Answer (score 12):

This likely is [*Dark Benediction* by Walter M. Miller Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Benediction). The disease was called "neuroderm", which is indeed "nerve-skin", and a derogatory term for the infected was "grey-skins". The sensorial improvement and intelligence increases are all present in the story.

(The disease in itself was not sentient *per se*; it had come from outer space as a *benediction* from an alien people who recognized that its neurosymbionts had been crucial in the race's development, and therefore wanted to gift them to other races).